# Wygwam not retaining Channel Images images

Tags: wygwam, channel-images

I want to use the Channel Images integration for Wygwam, but there seem to be two issues:

1.) No matter which size I choose for the image, it always uses the smallest image (I have 3 sizes set in the CI field).
2.) The image disappears from the Wygwam field when I edit the entry.

Anyone know what's going on? Perhaps a bug?

I'm using:
EE 2.9.2
Wygwam: 3.3.3
CI: 5.4.19

Comment: Did you eventually figure it out?
I currently experience the same issue with EE 3.1.2 CI: 6.0.1 and Wygwam 4.0.1

Comment: No, this was never resolved, unfortunately.